# Como enviar un formulario por email

Tags: php

un usuario realiza un pedido y este se almacena en una base de datos. Una vez rellenado el formulario deseo que mande un correo al usuario con los datos del formulario. Pues por mas que intento hacerlo no lo consigo.

Este es el echo del formulario.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" name="formcontacto" id="formcontacto">
    <div class="form-group" id="idTake">
   <label>Numero pedido:</label>
  <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["idTake"];?></strong></label>
</div>   
    <div class="form-group" id="name">
   <label>Nombre: </label>
 <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["name"];?></strong> </label>
     </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="strTelefono">
    <label>Teléfono: </label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strTelefono"];?></strong></label>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="strEmail">
    <label>E-mail: </label>
   <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strEmail"];?></strong></label>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="strHora">
     <label>Hora de recogida: </label>
       <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strHora"];?></strong></label>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="white-space: pre-line;" id="strNombre">
       <label>Pedido:</label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strNombre"];?></strong></label>
     </div>
   <input type="submit" class="botonBO" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="botoninsertar" />
        </form>
```

Y este es el codigo de enviar.php

```
    <?php require_once('../Connections/restaurante.php');
if(!empty($_POST['idTake'])     &&
   !empty($_POST['name'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['strEmail'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['strTelefono'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['strHora'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['strNombre'])     &&
   !filter_var($_POST['strEmail'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
}
$take = $_POST['idTake'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address= $_POST['strEmail'];
$phone = $_POST['strTelefono'];
$hora = $_POST['strHora'];
$message = $_POST['strNombre'];
$to = 'mianpol@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Contacto del sitio web:  $name";
$email_body = "Ha recibido un nuevo mensaje de su sitio web.\n\n"."Sus detalles:\n\nNºPedido: $take\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTelefono: $phone\n\nHora: $hora\n\nPedido:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@ElRinconcitodeJesus.es\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Llega el correo pero con los datos en blanco.
Y tampoco se como enviar el correo al usuario, ahora me los mando a mi.
Gracias

Comment: No estas usando <input> en tu formulario, por eso no se envia nada. En lugar de esto: `<strong><?php echo $row_R1["idTake"];?></strong>` pon esto: `<strong><?php echo $row_R1["idTake"];?></strong><input type="hidden" name="idTake" value="<?php echo $row_R1["idTake"];?>" />` en cada campo que quieras enviar, así evitarás que se muestren los campos pero al darle al submit los cogerá para enviar por POST.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias por tu rapidez y tu tiempo. Insisto MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0):

En ese formulario hay solo etiquetas `<label>`, no has introducido ningún dato dentro de un `<input>` para que sea enviado.

Prueba con este código.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" name="formcontacto" id="formcontacto">
  <div class="form-group" id="idTake">
    <label>Numero pedido:</label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["idTake"]; ?></strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="idTake" value="<?php echo $row_R1["idTake"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="name">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["name"]; ?></strong> </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row_R1["name"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="strTelefono">
    <label>Teléfono: </label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strTelefono"]; ?></strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="strTelefono" value="<?php echo $row_R1["strTelefono"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="strEmail">
    <label>E-mail: </label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strEmail"]; ?></strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="strEmail" value="<?php echo $row_R1["strEmail"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="strHora">
    <label>Hora de recogida: </label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strHora"]; ?></strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="strHora" value="<?php echo $row_R1["strHora"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="white-space: pre-line;" id="strNombre">
    <label>Pedido:</label>
    <label> <strong><?php echo $row_R1["strNombre"]; ?></strong></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="strNombre" value="<?php echo $row_R1["strNombre"]; ?>" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="botonBO" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="botoninsertar" />
</form>
```